# How compile a ROS package if previously I compiled ROS Cartographer

Tags: ros, catkin, cartographer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am testing Cartographer in a ROS Kinect installation.

In my catkin_ws I have installed ROS Cartographer following the notes from the documentation:
https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

and I tested some demos so the installation run nice.

Later, I have created a new package but when I try to compile:

```
-- ~~  traversing 6 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - ceres-solver (plain cmake)
-- ~~  - cartographer (plain cmake)
-- ~~  - cartographer_ros_msgs
-- ~~  - cartographer_ros
-- ~~  - cartographer_new <- NEW ROS PACKAGE
-- ~~  - cartographer_rviz
```

I receive the following error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:95 (message):
  This workspace contains non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build
  a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation.  Try the
  'catkin_make_isolated' command instead.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:63 (catkin_workspace)
```

I tried with catkin_make and catkin_make_isolated but I can´t solve the problem.

I think that it is a error from a beginner.

Many thanks in advance.

Juan Antonio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266507/how-compile-a-ros-package-if-previously-i-compiled-ros-cartographer/) by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2017-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should look into using [catkin_tools](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead of `catkin_make`. `catkin_tools` is a more user-friendly wrapper around `catkin`. It handles package isolation better than `catkin_make`, and it has some nice features like being able to build packages individually. It's still technically in beta, but there are several businesses and organizations using it in production.

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2017-07-17**:
Many thanks it works nice.

```
sudo apt-get install python-catkin-tools
```